# unable to run sudo gulp. getting an error "Error: eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker is not installed. Try running `bower install`."

Tags: angularjs, npm, gulp

I am using NVM 6.11.4 for Angular JS version 1.4. I have installed these below packages.
Required Tools -

1. NPM - Node Package manager - npm is the package manager for javascript.
   Ref - Home Page and Installation
   Versions - node -v : v6.11.4, npm -v : 3.10.10
2. Yeoman - For generating the SCAFFOLDING  for our App.
   Ref - Home Page - Installation - Usage Guide
   Cmd - sudo npm install -g yo
   Versions - yo --version : 1.7.0
3. Bower - For the application dependency management.
   Ref - Home and Installation - Search Packages
   Cmd - sudo npm install -g bower
   Versions - yo --version : 1.7.0
4. Gulp - The JavaScript Task Runner and Automate and enhance your workflow.
   Ref - Home - Plugins
   Cmd - sudo npm install -g gulp-cli
   Versions - gulp -v : CLI version 3.9.1, Local version 3.9.1

I have been working on Angular 1.4. since long back but recently due to some system issue all setup crashed and stopped working.

I reinstalled all above modules but sudo gulp is failing with above error; although i have already installed bower.

these are Sudo Gulp logs error:
Error: Error: eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker is not installed. Try running `bower install`

After Installing Bower I am able to see the required bootstrap date-picker has been already installed.

Need solution how I can run my setup successfully?

```js
package.json {
  "name": "dashboardApp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp test"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@shopify/app-bridge": "^2.0.5",
    "agora-rtc-sdk-ng": "^4.6.3",
    "connect-modrewrite": "^0.10.1"
  },

  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.6.9",
    "browser-sync": "^2.2.3",
    "del": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-config-angular": "^0.2.0",
    "eslint-config-dustinspecker": "^0.1.0",
    "eslint-path-formatter": "^0.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "^0.2.0",
    "find-up": "^1.0.0",
    "glob": "^5.0.1",
    "gulp": "^3.8.7",
    "gulp-add-src": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-angular-filesort": "^1.0.4",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-chmod": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-connect": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-css-rebase-urls": "0.0.5",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.1.6",
    "gulp-eslint": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-if": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-inject": "^1.5.0",
    "gulp-jscs": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-jshint": "^1.8.4",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^0.10.0",
    "gulp-modify-css-urls": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-ng-html2js": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-notify": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-order": "^1.1.1",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-protractor": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-rev": "^5.1.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.0.4",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.1",
    "gulp-string-replace": "^0.4.0",
    "gulp-tslint": "^3.1.2",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.4",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.8",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.1.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^2.0.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.3",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.4.2",
    "karma-failed-reporter": "^0.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.3.8",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "^0.1.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.2.3",
    "karma-sinon": "^1.0.3",
    "lodash": "^3.6.0",
    "main-bower-files": "^2.0.0",
    "multi-glob": "^0.4.0",
    "phantomjs": "^1.9.18",
    "plato": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "^2.0.0",
    "require-dir": "^0.3.0",
    "run-sequence": "^1.0.2",
    "sinon": "^1.17.2",
    "streamqueue": "^1.1.0",
    "uglify-save-license": "^0.4.1",
    "underscore.string": "^3.0.1",
    "wiredep": "^2.2.0",
    "yargs": "^3.4.5"
  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRwk8.jpg)
[image]

```
enter code here
```

Comment: Bower Error on running gulp:-
[16:03:43] Starting 'bowerCopy'...
[16:03:43] Finished 'bowerCopy' after 94 ms
[16:03:43] Starting 'bowerInject'...
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Error: eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker is not installed. Try running `bower install`.